# How can I get the event of home page scroll in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to make a home page, where it starts, it shows logo in the title bar, when it scrolls down, I want to get the event,so I can hide logo in the title bar and then show one TextInput for search.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to use reacts lifecycle methods in your component...

```
var Box = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {windowWidth: window.innerWidth};
  },

  handleResize: function(e) {
    this.setState({windowWidth: window.innerWidth});
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>Current window width: {this.state.windowWidth}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Box />, mountNode);
```

I think this link should help :)

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html